# Turning off VBA editor auto-format of code lines

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm trying to accomplish a Debug.Print without a newline in Access 2007, as in http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?581952-RESOLVED-debug-print-with-no-newline

```
Debug.Print --no-newline ".";
```

However, the auto-syntax checker converts this when I move to a different line of code to:

```
Debug.Print --no - newline; ".";
```

I have tried turning off Options -> Auto Syntax Check but the problem still persists. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Debug.Print` does not have an option named *--no-newline*.  So when the VB Editor encounters the line you tried, it (incorrectly) guesses you want a subtraction and adjusts the code line based on that guess.

The unquoted semicolon after the text you want to `Debug.Print` is what actually suppresses the new line.  Consider this procedure ...

```vb
Public Sub PrintWithoutNewline()
    Debug.Print "A";
    Debug.Print "B";
End Sub
```

Calling that procedure in the Immediate window prints *"AB"* on one line, and leaves the insertion point (cursor) at the end of that line instead of at the start of a new line.

```vb
PrintWithoutNewline
AB
```

Comment: I see. That's easier than I was expecting (although the semicolon use is still a bit of an obscure design choice) - I guess the site I was following was for a different language version? Thanks anyway!

Comment: That question was misleading.  I think the author meant *"I want `Debug.Print` to operate as if it had a `--no-newline` option."*  But nobody actually mentioned there is no such option for `Debug.Print`.